# Ubuntu 20.04 pinta selected area image resize problem

Tags: resize, pinta

I have installed pinta in my Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04, the pinta resize option works via Ubuntu 18.04,but can not use its image resize option by selecting the below icon+pressing the Left-Ctrl + left Mouse click on Ubuntu 20.04?!

[image]

If possible i want to know, how run this option via pinta in Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks.